# Google карта не работает по HTTPS

Tags: google-maps-api

Google карта не отображается, если зайти на сайт по HTTPS, но спокойно отображаются по HTTP.

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что скрипт google maps api наверняка запускаете по http, в результате в консоли браузера mixed content и карта не отображается

Comment: А как запустить по https ? Кстати Скрипт гугл мэпс загружаю по https

Comment: Что в консоли? Какие ошибки?